# Low Pass Filter Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, smoothing

Is there a way in matlab to create a low pass filter, I know i can use the filter function but not sure how to use it, I've been given the following formula for my low pass H(z) = 1 (1 - z^-4)^2 / 16 (1 - z^-1)^2 with a 20Hz cutoff frequency

Comment: You can, but you need Signal Processing Toolbox. Otherwise you have to design it by hand.

Comment: @Phonon - added that to my answer, I had forgotten about that. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right `H(z)`? That looks more like a comb filter than a low-pass.

Comment: yea it is, do you know how i would use that formula in my low pass filter?

Answer (score 3):

The `filter` function allows you to apply a filter to a vector. You still need to provide the filter coefficients. If you look at [the documentation for filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html), you see that you need to specify two vectors `b` and `a` whose elements are coefficients of z in descending powers, where z is the frequency domain variable in a z-transform. Since you have an expression for your filter given as a z-transform, the coefficients are easy to find.  First, let's write the numerator of your filter:

```
(1/16)*(1 - z^-4)^2 = (1/16)*(1 - 2z^-4 + z^-16)
= (1/16)*(1 + 0z^-1 + 0z^-2 + 0z^-3 - 2z^-4 + 0z^5 + 0z^-6 ... + z^-16)
```

So the `b` vector is `b = (1/16)*[1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]`. Similarly, the `a` vector is `a = [1 -2 1]`. So now you can filter your data vector `x` to get a result `y` by simply doing `y = filter(b,a,x);`.

Having said all that, the H(z) you specify above is definitely not a low pass filter. It's more like some weird cascade of a comb filter with itself.

If you want to design your own filter, and assuming you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, the absolute simplest thing to do is design a filter using Matlab's [`fir1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/fir1.html) function:

```
h = fir1(N, 20/(Fs/2)); %# N is filter length, Fs is sampling frequency (Hz)
```

which you can then use in the `filter` function:

```
y = filter(h, 1, x); %# second param is 1 because this is an FIR filter
```

You will need to pick N yourself. Generally, larger N values make for better filters, where better = rejects more frequencies above 20 Hz. If your N value starts getting so big that it causes weird behavior (computational errors, slow implementations, unacceptable startup/ending transients in the resulting data) you might consider a more complicated filter design. The Mathworks documentation has [an overview](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/f9-131178c.html#f9-136613) of the various digital filter design techniques.

Comment: I'm new to signal processing, i've been given the following formula for my low pass H(z) = 1 (1 - z^-4)^2 / 16 (1 - z^-1)^2  can you tell me how i can use it, i have no idea all i've been told is that i need to create a low pass filter with a 20Hz cutoff frequency

Answer (score 2):

The formula you have given: H(z) = 1 (1 - z^-4)^2 / 16 (1 - z^-1)^2 is the filter's Z-transform. It is a rational function, which means your filter is a recursive (IIR) filter.
Matlab has a function called `filter(b,a,X)`. The b are the coefficients of the numerator with decreasing power of z, i.E. in your case: (1*z^-0 + 0*z^-1 + 0*z^-2 + 0*z^-3 + 0*z^-4)^2, you can use `conv()` for quantity square:

`b = [1 0 0 0 -1]`

`b = conv(b,b)`

and the coefficients of the denominator are:

`a = [1 -1]`

`a = 16 * conv(a,a)`

Then you call the filter `y = filter(b,a,x)`, where `x` is your input data.

You can also check your filter's frequency response with `freqz(b,a)`

Hope that helped.